# Azure AD B2C Signin from native app - To sign into this application the account must be added to the directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a new user in AD B2C tenant using AD Graph API.

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "passwordProfile": {
  "password": "Test@123",
  "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
},
  "signInNames": [
   {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "Dawn"
   },
   {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "dawn@example.com"
   },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "value": "96587XXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to login with these credential from the Android native app client using adal4j library. I'm able to login with Mobile number and UserName and I can get the access token. But when I tried to login with the Email Address I'm getting an error "To sign into this application the account must be added to the directory".

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Adal4j library doesn't support the Azure AD B2C flow. You need to implement this flow yourself if you want to use this flow with Java developing.
Please refer the code sample mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) to interact Azure AD B2C via the protocol you want.

In addition, to test the account login with policy we can run it from the portal like figure below. And based on the test it works well for me to login using the email of Azure AD B2C local account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have implemented P2 OAuth to authenticate on AD B2C in iOS. https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 First I would like to know whether it is a fair choice to use or not. However, with this library, I'm able to login using username and mobile number. But why not an email address? In user sign in policy when I click run now, I'm able to login with emailAddress and password.

Comment: The Azure AD B2C supports both local account and social account(Facebook and Google+ etc.) login. If you doesn't want to enable social account, you can choose the Azure Active Directory instead of Azure AD B2C. And to support the social account, we need to implement the Azure AD B2C OAuth flow which is different with stand OAuth. More detail about OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow of Azure AD B2C, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code#1-get-an-authorization-code).